# Excel 2007: Filtering out rows in a table based on a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a large table that looks like this:

```
ID      String
1       abcde
2       defgh
3       defgh
4       defgh
5       ijkl
6       ijkl
7       mnop
8       qrst
```

I want to selectivley hide rows by populating a list of filterd values. For example, I'd like to filter out (hide) all rows that contain 'ef', 'kl', and 'qr'. Is there an easy way to do this?

I know how to use Advanced filters to *include* only the rows that contain those substrings, but not the inverse. Has anyone does this before?

Comment: There is a "does not contain" option under autofilter, but this only permits two custom settings.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but for a variable length of strings. Two is insufficient for this application.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use the **Advanced Filters**. Here's how you can use it for your problem:

### Single Criterion

Here's a way to exclude or hide cells that contain the substring "ef."

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

This is the formula in **A13**:

```
=ISERROR(SEARCH($B$13,B2))
```

which works the same as: `=ISERROR(SEARCH("ef",B2))`

Note the usage of absolute and relative references. The 2nd reference (**B2**) points to the *first item in your data range*; in order for the filter to work, it needs to be *relative*. The reference that points to the text substring that you don't want to include needs to be absolute.

Also, the Criteria range needs to have a **blank header**; although you have include it when setting up your advanced filter (see the Criteria range field in the screenie).

---

### Multiple Criteria

This example hides cells that contain the substrings "ef", "j" and "rs."

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Here's the formula in **A13** this time:

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$13,B2)),
     ISERROR(SEARCH($B$14,B2)),
     ISERROR(SEARCH($B$15,B2)))
```

or you could use:

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("ef",B2)),
     ISERROR(SEARCH("j",B2)),
     ISERROR(SEARCH("rs",B2)))
```

Comment: Bah! Imgur ruined the screenie :(

Comment: Thanks for the awesome screens, however I need to do the exact opposite of this. I want to hide rows in the table based on a criteria range, not include them. Any idea on how to invert this?

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry if the screenies are ugly.

Answer (score 1):

One easy and wholly inelegant way I can think of is setting up another column to check if the value in your target column contains your filter strings.

Your formula would look something like

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ef",B2)),1,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("kl",B2)),1,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("qr",B2)),1,0)`

You could then autofilter on 0.

Comment: This is close - if there was a way to say FIND(C:C,B2) and have it return true if any of the string in column C were present in B2 I would be all set.

Comment: @Sam Johnson, You can do that with an array formula. =IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND($C:$C,B2),0))=0,0,1) entered by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.  Use that formula in Row 2, then fill down.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question dates more than one year, but you can use the conditional formatting if you havent figured it out yet.